# How to remove word from .split function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have written a program that extracts text from a given webpage.

I used .split to put the words into an array. I'd like to remove any word that does not start with a letter e.g. 5X would not be classed as a word but X5 would be.

My code doesn't work.

```
function getWords(node) {
    var text = node.innerText;
    output.textContent = inputValidation(text)
}
function inputValidation(text) {
    var wordData = text.split();
    for (i in wordData) {
        if (isLetter(i[0] == False)) {
            wordData.splice(i, 1);
        }

    } return wordData
}

function isLetter(str) {
    return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily pack this into a filter, like so:

```js
let output = document.querySelector("#output");
getWords(document.querySelector("p"));

function getWords(node) {
  let text = node.innerText;
  output.textContent = text.split(" ").filter(word => word[0].toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]{1}/));
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world! Click here Goodbye world! X7 9x</p>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Using your code it goes from "Hello world! Click here Goodbye world! X7 9x" to "Hello,world!,here,world!,X7" so it's skipping a few words for some reason. It does successfully skip the incorrect word.

Comment: As you can see from the edit I just made, it also works with them

Comment: thanks it must be an error in my code. I'm used text nodes to retrieve the text.

Comment: Oh, ok. I assumed `node` referred to DOM Nodes, and that you were using HTML Elements

Comment: I eventually got it working by removing the extra white spaces from my indented text with text.split(/\s+/g)

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be incorrect as you are passing `boolean` value in `isLetter` function as `isLetter(i[0] == False)` which is again incorrect as `F` should be lowercase i.e, `false`. There are plenty of error in your code but you can however use `parseInt()` and `isNaN()` to check that the entire word start with character or digit.

```js
//when you have a letter as a first character
var word = 'X5';
var isLetter = isNaN(parseInt(word));
console.log(isLetter);

//when you dont have a letter as a first character
word = '5ABC';
isLetter = isNaN(parseInt(word));
console.log(isLetter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your isLetter to

```
function isLetter(str) {
if (str.match(/^\d/)) {
   return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on this line of code

```
    if (isLetter(i[0] == False)) {
```

should be

```
    if (isLetter(i[0]) == False) {
```

or better

```
    if (!isLetter(i[0])) {
```

Comment: I amended to this but did not fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var text="abc def 10hij kl 3GH";

var splitedtext=text.split(" ");
var dummyarray=[];

for(var i=0;i<splitedtext.length;i++){
    var thistext=parseInt(splitedtext[i]);
  if( thistext.toString() == "NaN" ){
        dummyarray.push(splitedtext[i]);
  }
}

$("body").html(dummyarray.join(" "));
```

jsfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/hztdxv4w/2/